# regex multiple string match in a python list

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list of strings like this:

`["ra", "dec", "ra-error", "dec-error", "glat", "glon", "flux", "l", "b"]`

I need to find all the strings in this list that contain `"ra"` or `"dec"` or `"lat"`

I checked many other threads as well as the regex manual. It turned out to be too confusing for me. Pleas help. :(

Comment: You don't need regex for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using regex if that's what you really need. I search to see if any of your 3 substrings are present inside any given string from the list. Using https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html as the Python regex library.

```
import re
for word in wordList:
  m = re.search('.*(ra|dec|lat).*', word)
  if m:
    <youve matched here>
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need regex for this at all. A list comprehension with `any` will suffice

```
>>> subs = ['ra', 'dec', 'lat']
>>> strings = ["ra", "dec", "ra-error", "dec-error", "glat", "glon", "flux", "l", "b"]
>>> [s for s in strings if any(i in s for i in subs)]
['ra', 'dec', 'ra-error', 'dec-error', 'glat']
```

Answer (score 0):

`find` also works for your problem.

```
a=["ra", "dec", "ra-error", "dec-error", "glat", "glon", "flux", "l", "b"]
b=[]
for i in a:
    if i.find("ra")!=-1:
        b.append(i)
    if i.find("dec")!=-1:
        b.append(i)
    if i.find("lat")!=-1:
        b.append(i)
print b

b=['ra', 'dec', 'ra-error', 'dec-error', 'glat']
```