# How can i match a list of strings against another

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, match

I have 2 lists of strings:

```
['Tipo de fertilizante',
 'N',
 'P2O5',
 'K2O',
 'S',
 'CaO',
 'MgO',
 'Zn',
 'Solubilidad g/100cc H2O',
 'Precio (€/100 kg)',
 '€/UF (N)',
 '€/UF (P2O5)',
 '€/UF (K2O)',
 '€/UF (S)',
 '€/UF (CaO)',
 '€/UF (MgO)',
 'JERARQUIA - (N)',
 'JERARQUIA - (P2O5)',
 'JERARQUIA - (K2O)',
 'JERARQUIA - (S)',
 'JERARQUIA - (CaO)',
 'JERARQUIA - (MgO)',
 'Abono']
```

and this is second one:

```
['JERARQUIA - (N)',
 'JERARQUIA - (P2O5)',
 'JERARQUIA - (K2O)',
 'JERARQUIA - (S)',
 'JERARQUIA - (CaO)',
 'JERARQUIA - (MgO)']
```

I want to get elements of the first one that are contained in the elements of the second one so the desired result would be:

```
['N',
 'P2O5',
 'K2O',
 'S',
 'CaO',
 'MgO', 
 'JERARQUIA - (N)',
 'JERARQUIA - (P2O5)',
 'JERARQUIA - (K2O)',
 'JERARQUIA - (S)',
 'JERARQUIA - (CaO)',
 'JERARQUIA - (MgO)',]
```

I've looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45337752/regex-multiple-string-match-in-a-python-list) answer and this is what i've tried:

```
[s for s in list_1 if any(i in s for i in list_2)]
```

but the result i get is:

```
['JERARQUIA - (N)',
 'JERARQUIA - (P2O5)',
 'JERARQUIA - (K2O)',
 'JERARQUIA - (S)',
 'JERARQUIA - (CaO)',
 'JERARQUIA - (MgO)']
```

This is not what i want. After a lot of back and fourth with this, i still don't get how I can achieve the result I need.

How can i do this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `'P2O5'` etc aren't in the second list, why are these expected to be returned too?

Comment: @Sayse They are, as substrings. Look well :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
[s for s in list_1 if any(s in i for i in list_2)]
```

(explanation: we check for s in i instead of i in s in your example, that makes the difference in the result)

Comment: @Miguel2488 - if you add `AR` to `list_1`, probably you will be a bit surprised from the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by nested for loops.
It will make the programme a bit lengthy, but it will give u a surety that it will work.

```
list_3 = []
for i in list_1:
    for j in list_2:
        if i == j:
            list_3.append(i)
```

Do try it this way.